# Music folder doesn't fully load?

Tags: windows-7

My music library doesn't fully load, in the sense that when I open it, I see only about 20 files (it should contain over 2000), and no subfolders are shown either.

See the screenshot below (click for larger version):

[image]

How can I get this to be normal again?

Comment: what version of windows are you using? we need all the info you can give us.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "no maps are shown either"?

Comment: I use windows 7 on a laptop. And with no maps I mean there are a few maps in My Music map, but he doens't show them. (Thnx for answering so quickly!)

Comment: @Joel I'm still a bit confused about what exactly you mean by maps. Do you mean albums or subfolders? A screenshot might be helpful.

Comment: what is the difference between them/ Because I have albums and subfolders in My Music, but he doesn't load them (but they are there, because when I search for them, then he dóes load them) here is a pic:http://postimg.org/image/tgczt16r1/

Comment: By "music folder" do you mean the Music Library or something else? I'm also confused about what "maps" are.

Comment: I am confused by who "he" is.

Comment: Music folder is "my Music". See pic (on the left hand side)

Comment: @Joel The image is really small, can you try uploading a full-size one? Anyway, from what I can see, you've opened your Music library and can only see a few dozen files (tracks), but no folders (which I guess is what you mean by "maps"). Can you check which folders are included in your Music library? Right-click on it in the left-hand navigation pane and select Properties.

Comment: @Indrek yes I'm sorry, will upload a full one. Youre right about everything. I have a lot of other folders in my music map, but he only shows this in properties: http://postimg.org/image/jxtzut65f/

Comment: As you can see in the top bar, it is still loading (it's about 98% loaded he says), after 15 minutes...

Comment: @Joel When did this problem start? Can you go directly to **C:\Gebruikers\Joel\Mijn muziek** and see if the files and folders show up there? Also, see here for information about using Libraries in Windows 7: http://windows.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows7/products/features/libraries (I'm assuming you're Dutch, apologies in advance if I'm wrong).

Comment: @Indrek this problem started 2 weeks ago. Hey i just did what you said, (gebruikers/joel/mijn muziek) and there i can see everything! And yes you are correct, i am dutch haha

Comment: but how come the music folder does not load everything? It is exactly the same folder...?

Comment: does all the music show up when opened from windows media player?